# Compressed images files not showing up in html page

Tags: video, mp4, jpeg2000

I compressed the files gif to mp4 and jpeg to jpeg2000 but when I specify this in my code the background image does not show up

Names are correctly spelled

```
header {
  text-align: center;
  background: url('./banner.jpg' /*to jp2*/) no-repeat top center;
  /* background-size: cover; */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  background-size: 100%;
}

<img src="./longBoard.gif/*to mp4 */" alt="Person Longboarding Downhill" class="hobies-image">
```

Picture and gif to show up

Comment: I would recommend to use your Web Developer Tools (F12 in nearly every browser) and check the Network tab to see the elements being loaded. At least in your `<img>` tag there is an error as `/* comment */` is a comment in CSS and JS, but in HTML it has to be `<!-- Comment -->`. I would also recommend to not add comments somewhere in a property assignment, e.g. it should read `background: url('./banner.jpg') no-repeat top center;`.

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply i just added this, to show what i was trying to change. I am on the network tab but do not know how to see elements being loaded i will search this

Comment: After you open the tools, you have to reload the page (F5 it) and then you'll see all request ;)

Comment: Focused title on issue

Answer (score 0):

Although JPEG 2000 is [supported by the Safari browser](https://caniuse.com/#search=jpeg2000), it has not been adopted by other browsers and is not a format that is generally used on the web.

H.264 in MP4 is [supported by most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=mp4), but it is a video format and should be used with a `<video>` tag.  For example:

```
  <video src="myvideo.mp4" controls>
  </video>
```